# Angular 2 How to avoid many conditions (ngIf) in templates?

Tags: angular

In some cases i have a lot of conditions in templates, e.g. i have many conditions into ngIf. How i can reduce conditions, it would be better to use one condition to show that div, or use some method to handling conditions and hide/show element.

```html
<div (click)="createMessage()" class="message" *ngIf="array.length && message.queue && message.queue.length && !state || array.length && message.text && message.text.length && !state">
</div>
```

Comment: Move them out of the template into the components class and refer to it in `*ngIf`, or maintain a single variable that you use in `*ngIf` that is updated when one of the conditions changes, this way the expression isn't executed every time change detection runs.

Comment: thank you but everything is not clear for me. If i will use one variable for this case how this variable will be updating with many conditions ? Can you give me an example please

Comment: You need to update this variable every time any of the parts of the expression changes. I don't know if this is practical in your case. I don't know when such changes happen in your code.

Comment: "You need to update this variable every time any of the parts of the expression changes." I have no idea how i should do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the `*ngIf` condition length by calling a custom method from the component.

```
<div (click)="createMessage()" class="message" *ngIf="showCreateMessage(array,message)"></div>
```

//Method name is not meaningful because I don't know your exact requirement.

In your Component

```
showCreateMessage(array:any,message:any)
{
  return array.length && message.queue && message.queue.length && !state || array.length && message.text && message.text.length && !state;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the Snippet feature if the code is not actually runnable inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really reduce it to expression one unless you delegate this into a function and pass parameters but you can try something like :

`*ngIf="!state && array.length && ( message?.queue.length  || message?.text.length)"`

Comment: thank you but i thought i can write smth like that: *ngIf="condition" or *ngIf="condition()"

Comment: Sure, you can write something like that. Using functions in bindings is discouraged though because they are checked very frequently and might slow down your application notable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your last comment, I was looking for that exact same topic. Do you know where can I find some more information about the difference (behind the scenes) between `*ngIf="conditionInTemplate"` and `*ngIf="conditionInComponent()"`?.

Comment: In the former `conditionInTemplate` is a field or getter, in the later it is a function. You need to be careful with getters and functions in view bindings, they can be called quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Better than call the function in the .html, You can use a variable and **each time** message or array change you write (I suppose after a call in service or click a button to add an element to an array)

```
this.show=this.showCreateMessage(this.array,this.message)
```

then a simple `*ngIf="show"` make the trick